# How to manage fedora services and daemons using the GUI?

Tags: fedora, gui, services, daemon

I am using Fedora 17, I need a GUI program to start/stop and enable/disable services and daemons.

I have installed "system-config-services" but it did not have enable/disable feature(run it with sudo).

[image]

Is there any GUI program to do this?

Comment: I see rcconf in debian based linux, this is sufficient for me in fedora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RHEL/CentOs/Fedora You can use below tools

- ncurses based tool for enabling/disabling : `ntsysv`
- GUI for starting/stoping  : `system-config-services`

Comment: I have installed "system-config-services" but it did not have enable/disable feature.

Comment: you will find check boxes just tick/untick any service which you want to enable/disable at startup.

Comment: if possible upload screen shot of `system-config-services`

Comment: I uploaded it in question.

Comment: you may have to run it as root!?